# GeocoderDotUS Geopy ('NoneType' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, exception, geopy

```
import csv
from geopy import geocoders
import time

g = geocoders.GeocoderDotUS()

spamReader = csv.reader(open('locations.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')

f = open("output.txt",'w')

for row in spamReader:
a = ', '.join(row)
#exactly_one = False
time.sleep(1)


place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(a)


b = str(place) + "," + "[" + str(lat) + "," + str(lng) + "]" + "\n"
print b
f.write(b)
```

I can't really determine why I am receiving

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Penguin\workspace\geocode-nojansdatabase\src\yahoo.py", line 17, in 
    place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(a)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable*

I checked to make sure there was a value in a before the geocode(a) call was placed. Perhaps a match was not found? If that is the case the I guess I just have to add in an if not b then statement. Does anyone know more about this?

I am seeing that adding a

```
a = ', '.join(row)
print(a)
```

Does yield:
178 Connection Rd Pomona QLD

Comment: A copy of the full traceback/error will help pinpoint the error location, can you add this to your question.

Comment: `spamReader` is apparently not iterable, meaning there are no rows to loop over.  Are you certain that `locations.csv` is in the same directory as your script?

Comment: Yes. I am in the eclipse environment and it does say that locations.csv is in there.

Comment: The first entry in locations.csv is 178 Connection Rd Pomona QLD

Comment: a then contains that value 178 Connection Rd...

Comment: If a has a value and I see it in the debugger then the for loop was entered at least one time... No?

Comment: So I see you are asking for the whole traceback Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Penguin\workspace\geocode-nojansdatabase\src\yahoo.py", line 17, in <module>
    place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(a)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I have tried turning on additional exception handling which is still yielding the same exception to come out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a, (b, c) = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>> a, (b, c) = ('foo', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Your guess is correct. Check before unpacking.

Comment: Alright so I am wondering how to find out where is the base package name for GeocoderDotUS. Either there is some exception or GeocoderDotUS is not working.

Comment: What I am really asking I think is does anyone know what to put in the except block for this code?

Comment: ... How do you expect to figure out what went wrong with only the exception?

Comment: That is my point as well. How are exceptions for GeocoderDotUS handled that is what I am asking...

Comment: They're *not* exceptions, as you've seen.

Comment: OK. So do you have any suggestions on how to handle ["error=2: couldn't find this address! sorry"]?

Comment: My intent would be to skip over that address and move on to the next one.

Comment: My suggestion would be to just look at the return value.

Comment: Darn... I am looking for the Python syntax.. Check for none.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12007/discussion-between-sepoto-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)